# avoid empty arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have this code

```
let defCores = el.histories;
let cores = [];
for(let i = 0; i < defCores.length; i++){
    cores.push({
        new_core: defCores[i].new_core.name,
        new_color: defCores[i].new_core.color,
        old_core: defCores[i].old_core.name,
        old_color: defCores[i].old_core.color,
    })
}

// using `cores` in my template to show (append data)
let myCores = '';
cores.forEach(core => {
    myCores += "<div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block; clear:both; margin-bottom: 5px;'>"+
    "<div class='coreColor' style='display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 15px; background: "+core.old_color+";'></div>"+
    "<div class='coreName' style='margin-left: 5px; display: inline-block; width: 25%;'>" + core.old_core + "</div>"+
    "<div class='coreName' style='display: inline-block;'><i style='color: red;' class='fas fa-arrow-right'></i> <i style='color: seagreen;' class='fas fa-arrow-left'></i></div>"+
    "<div class='coreName' style='margin-left: 5px; display: inline-block; width: 25%;'>" + core.new_core + "</div>"+
    "<div class='coreColor' style='width: 20px; display: inline-block; height: 15px; background: "+core.new_color+";'></div>"+
    "</div>";
});
```

But my data some have `let defCores = el.histories;` array some are empty. like:

[image: one]

Because of this I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

which comes from this line: `new_core: defCores[i].new_core.name,`

Now I'm seeking for solution to avoid this error and if my `histories` array have value return it if not just ignore it (show nothing)

> PS: I thought `for(let i = 0; i < defCores.length; i++){` would prevent such issue on empty histories but apparently not!

**Any idea?**

Comment: The error doesn't appear to be caused by the empty arrays. The problem seems to be that some of the array entries have a `new_core` value of `null` and you can't read the `name` property of a `null`.

Comment: Add a `?` to the end of the property, like `defCores[i[?.new_core?.name` This will is a newer JS operator that only "goes on" to the next selector if the current one doesn't return undefined

Comment: @VirxEC that is working man, thank you

Comment: @mafortis you can check my answer that will help you

Comment: @NarendraChouhan just replied to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this by binding the key in the object conditionally

```
let defCores = el.histories;
let cores = [];
for (let i = 0; i < defCores.length; i++) {
    let obj = {
        ... (defCores[i] && defCores[i].new_core.name && { new_core: defCores[i].new_core.name }),
        ... (defCores[i] && defCores[i].new_core.color && { new_color: defCores[i].new_core.color }),
        ... (defCores[i] && defCores[i].old_core.name && { old_core: defCores[i].old_core.name }),
        ... (defCores[i] && defCores[i].old_core.color && { old_color: defCores[i].old_core.color })
    }
    if (obj && Object.keys(obj).length) {
        cores.push(obj)
    }

}
```

Comment: still says `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null` on `var obj = _objectSpread({}, defCores[i] && defCores[i].new_core.name && {`

Comment: I went and check database two of my histories didn't have value for `old_core, new_core` therefore error was because of them :/ and your code is working.

Comment: great @mafortis

Answer (score 0):

I think adding an `if` check for your code should work.

```
let defCores = el.histories;

if (defCores && defCores.length) {
  let cores = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < defCores.length; i++){
    ...
  }

  let myCores = '';
  cores.forEach(core => {
    ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add an empty array check:

```
for(let i = 0; i < defCores.length; i++){
  if(defCores[i].new_core.name) {
    cores.push({
      new_core: defCores[i].new_core.name,
      new_color: defCores[i].new_core.color,
      old_core: defCores[i].old_core.name,
      old_color: defCores[i].old_core.color,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: this hides all my histories even those which has data

Comment: Now if check is even more specific. Try this brother. Let us know whether its working or not.